# How can i convert pdf stored in google app engine blobstore blob to text

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob

I have uploaded pdf's to google appe engine blobstore now how can i read each  pdf from the blob so that they can be converted to text and stored in a new blob as text. Currently i am unable to read pdf data from blob

Comment: What are you having problems with? The process of reading the data from App Engine, converting PDF to text or storing the new data?

Comment: currently i am having problem in reading data from the blob, basically its a pdf file , i want to access it in such a way so that it can be converted to text using pypdf